# What is the ideal directory structure for Django deployed app on openshift?

Tags: python, django, openshift

I am successfully deploy my application in open shift with first hello message but now 
I want an ideal directory structure for deploy on openshift this
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the [django-example](https://github.com/openshift/django-example) repo from Openshift. You have an example project from where you can get the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
project
    appname-1/
    appname-2/
    appname-n/
    static/ # to store your static files
    project/
        wsgi.py # file created by django-admin startproject
    templates/
    wsgi/
        static/ # in your settings.py set this folder as your STATIC_ROOT
    manage.py
    setup.py # file created by openshift python cartridge
    wsgi.py # file created by openshift python cartridge
```

When you do a `git push` to your openshift remote, all of these files and folders will be created in $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR. The special folder `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static` is used to bypass wsgi and serve the files directly using apache. For this reason you must set this folder as your STATIC_ROOT to collect all of your static files.

Also for storing user uploaded files you should create a folder under $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. For example, `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media`. This folder will be persisted across future deploys.

If you use sqlite3 for you database your settings should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(os.getenv($OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR), 'media'),
    }
}
```